# How to group SQLite results by date in UITable?

Tags: ios, sqlite, date

I am currently redesigning my diabetes management app and want to be able to group logged measurements(which are stored in database) by day/week/month/custom in UITableView.

http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/

This tutorial explained the UItableView part pretty well, but I am having trouble to to figure out how to get the dates(for example if I only have measurements in 3 weeks out of 4 in current month) and query the database based on that.

Would appreciate any advice.

Comment: Your question is not precise enough. The example you posted uses the calendar API, not SQLite, so it's pretty useless. It's a pretty basic thing.

Comment: Sorry about that. My question is basically this- say I have 2 measurements this week, and 3 last, how can I group them in my UITableView?